# Unable to run two separate select statements Oracle / Toad ORA-00933

Tags: sql, toad

I'm coming from a MS SQL background using SSMS. I just recently started using Oracle / Toad at a new company and I'm finding it to be a bit finicky.

One of the things that I use to do in SSMS was select 2 queries, and then execute the statement and see the results for both.

When I attempt to run the following queries

```
select count(*) from table1;
select count(*) from table2;
```

I get the following error message back: ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended

Is there something in particular that I'm not doing correct?

Answer (score 4):

In your tool, hit F5, you'll get your results as a script for both queries.

In the free, [official GUI for Oracle Database](http://www.oracle.com/sqldeveloper), you can do this:

[image]

As Barbaros Özhan notes, you'll need to fix your queries first. You need to do a count() on SOMETHING - * will work.

Comment: No, he's asking how to run two queries at once. The queries will run, with problems or not. The tools offer different approaches at running multiple statements at once.

Comment: One of the things that I use to do in SSMS was select 2 queries, and then execute the statement and see the results for both.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.

Comment: He's seeing the results for ONE query - which is the ORA- error. If he wants to see both in toad, use F5.

Comment: It was a mixture of both, A) what was I doing wrong, and B) If I wasn't doing something wrong with my select statement(s), then why was that error firing.

Comment: Welcome to Oracle @Dcarr. Most of the orcl tools out there have many things in common with SSMS. If you can't find something, it's probably just called something different.

Comment: PL/SQL Developer gives you tabbed results grids for multiple queries. And it's way cheaper than Toad. Just saying.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Unfortunately I'm new and currently tied to what the company uses, maybe down the line I can get them to use something else. I figured out the issue however, I was not using the shortcut keys and selecting the statements I wanted to run and then hitting the button "Execute/Compile statement at caret" in Toad instead of selecting the "Execute as script" button. Apparently using the first button tries to the scripts as a single statement.

Comment: @Dcarr the first button there is designed for a single statement only - that's the entire reason i offered up this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer apparently was the button that I was selecting in Toad for Oracle / slightly incorrect SQL statement.

I was hitting the "Execute / compile statement at caret" button instead of the "Execute Script As" button. 
[Selecting the wrong button in Toad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe33E.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include some literal like `'x'`, or a symbol like `*` or a number `1` inside `count` function like `count(1)` or `count(*)` or `count('x')`.

In your case, one of these missing operators causes `ORA-00933`.

Comment: Looks like the star character was present in the original code but getting hidden by the site formatting. I indented the code and it appeared.